# What is the intuition behind separability of normed spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

We say a given space $X=(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is separable when it has a countable dense subspace.I do understand it the surface level as to how do we prove a space is separable. But I am unable to understand at the abstract level as to what exactly the separability property of a space points out in the space.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: The countability of the dense subspace is the main aspect of separability. It allows you, among other things, to show certain results only for this dense subset, and then obtain the same for all the space by an approximation argument

Comment: @ajay It's sep**a**rability (though it has nothing to do with "separation").

Comment: thankyou for correcting me.

Comment: One idea behind separability is that you can approximate every vector by a finite linear combination of vectors coming from a countable set. This gives you a way to reduce many arguments to finite-dimensional cases. In a sense, such a space is "constructible."

Answer (score 2):

My answer is not a rigorous one, but a practical one.

Separable normed spaces are nice enough that you can prove a lot of things on a countable, dense subset and then have the property for the whole space via a density argument.

For non-separable spaces, it's simply not enough to consider a countable subset, which makes a lot of arguments harder (or even fail).

As to how to prove separability: You need some intuition which kind of set can act as a countable basis for your vector space (e.g. the sequences $\{e_i=(0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots), i=1,\dots\}$ (which have the $1$ at the $i$-place) for the $\ell^p$ spaces, or polynomials with rational coefficients for $C[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you please explain using an example as to how  using a density argument on dense subset we conclude the result on the whole space.